# JavaBean and relation with BeanInfo, are they related?

Tags: java, javabeans, pojo, beaninfo

Is there any relationship between JavaBean and [BeanInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html)? I read various posts/questions and about Java Bean it is mentioned a bean is a regular class which adheres to some rule (private data members, getters() , setters(), implements [Serializabe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface...).

I was going through book "Java Complete reference, 8th Edition" and came across BeanInfo, in chapter on "Java Beans". What relation a Java Bean has with BeanInfo?

Although I tried to find on various posts, I am still not able to fully understand how Java beans are helpful, how does following some rules by a class (thereby making it a bean) makes it helpful which a regular Java class can't do?

Comment: Read [The Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/TOC.html) by Oracle, free of cost.

Comment: The [JavaBeans specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) is remarkably easy to read if you want all the details.

Comment: While originally meant to be "a  reusable software component that can be manipulated visually in a builder tool", JavaBeans are used in ways other than in a form-building [IDE tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). For example, as a convenient data container, [BeanItem](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/BeanItem.html), in the [Vaadin data model](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.items.html).

Comment: By the way, do not confuse [JavaBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) with [Enterprise JavaBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans) (EJB). Technically unrelated. The first is easy to understand with simple practical application. The second… well, not so much. EJB is a whole other beast whose name was given by marketers trying to leverage the initial buzz and reputation of JavaBeans in the early days of Java technology.

Comment: @BasilBourque: Thanks so much for your inputs, i would go thru the links provided by you.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

- **Implicit**

  - The getter/setter method naming conventions implicitly identify properties when the class is considered to be a [JavaBean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans).
- **Explicit**

  - Alternatively, you can identify those properties explicitly by defining a partner class that implements the [`BeanInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) interface.
  - In Java 9 and later, you may use [annotations](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/256) to more conveniently implement `BeanInfo`.

## Details

The [JavaBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) [spec](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) was originally meant to be "a reusable software component that can be manipulated visually in a builder tool" such as drag-and-drop [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) form-building tools. That never really worked out.

Instead, people commonly use the JavaBeans approach as a way of identifying properties. For example, the [`BeanItemContainer`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/BeanItemContainer.html) in [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) 7.

At a minimum, a JavaBean must:

- Be [serializable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)
- Have a [no-args constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)
- Have getter/setter methods ([“mutators”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method)) matching a naming convention

You can define a JavaBean either implicitly or explicitly.

## JavaBean naming conventions

The implicit way to define a JavaBean is through naming conventions. Any methods starting with `get`, `set`, or `is` are detected by [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming))/[introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) and considered to identify a property. The imaginary property may or may not indeed be backed by a member variable on the class.

If a `Person` class has `getEyeColor` and `setEyeColor` methods, then as a JavaBean we perceive a read-write “eyeColor” property. A getter without a setter makes the property read-only.

## `BeanInfo` interface

The explicit way to define a JavaBean is to create another class alongside you intended JavaBean class. The other class implements the [`BeanInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) interface. Most likely the other class is actually a subclass of the `SimpleBeanInfo` class. That `SimpleBeanInfo` class implements the `BeanInfo` interface in a negative manner, denying info. You override the methods for the pieces of info you want to identify aspects of your JavaBean class.

You can use the `BeanInfo` partner class to identify the properties (instead of using the getter/setter naming convention). And you can identify other aspects of a JavaBean. Many of those other aspects are outmoded as they relate to the JavaBean being a widget to appear in an IDE form-building tool, but you may still find some aspects useful.

The reflection/introspection facilities in Java automatically detect and process your BeanInfo classes to provide the meta-data about your JavaBean classes.

See [Oracle Tutorial page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/beaninfo.html).

## BeanInfo Annotations

[Java 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) may help with some aspects of a JavaBean: [annotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation). I have not yet understood their proper usage. I have asked in another Question, [*How to use new BeanInfo Annotations in Java 9*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776211/how-to-use-new-beaninfo-annotations-in-java-9). I had hoped this would allow annotating member variables as properties to avoid having to write empty getter/setter methods — but apparently this JEP does not provide this feature (I'm not entirely sure).

See [JEP 256: BeanInfo Annotations](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/256) on the [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net) project.

## JavaBeans spec

There is much more to JavaBeans than just properties like “eyeColor”, though properties are certainly the most common purpose for using JavaBeans.

I suggest studying the quite readable [JavaBeans 1.01 specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html). And read the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/TOC.html).

For a technical overview, I suggest reading this posting, [The JavaBeans specification](http://blog.joda.org/2014/11/the-javabeans-specification.html) by Stephen Colebourne.

## Bean Validation

On a related note… The [Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org) standard is becoming a popular way to declare and enforce business rules for the conditions on data values within an object. For example, rules might be "eye color is a required field, and must not be null or empty string" or "invoice total must be zero or positive, never a negative number".

There have been [three versions of the standard](http://beanvalidation.org/specification/) (1.0, 1.1 in [JSR 349](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=349), & [2.0](http://beanvalidation.org/news/2017/02/14/bean-validation-2-0-early-draft-released/) in [JSR 380](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=380)) and various implementations. Bean Validation can be used at either client-side (Swing, JavaFX, etc.) or server-side. [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com), for example, supports its own technology for validation during data-entry as well as [supporting you plugging in](https://dzone.com/articles/bean-validation-vaadin-7) a Bean Validation implementation.

## Enterprise JavaBeans

Do not confuse JavaBeans with [Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans). Re-using the “JavaBean” trademark for EJB was a poor decision by the Sun marketing staff. EJB is totally unconnected and distinct from the original JavaBeans.

## Records

If what you want is a simple way to represent structured data as properties in a Java object, look into the new *Records* feature being previewed in Java 14. See [*JEP 359*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359).

> Records provide a compact syntax for declaring classes which are transparent holders for shallowly immutable data.