# How to use new BeanInfo Annotations in Java 9

Tags: java, properties, annotations, javabeans, jep-256

[*JEP 256: BeanInfo Annotations*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/256) provides for [`JavaBean`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/beans/JavaBean.html) and [`BeanProperty`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/beans/BeanProperty.html) annotations. While there is not much documentation, I have been hoping this would allow us to use annotations to designate fields on a class as being JavaBean-style properties without having to create boilerplate [getter/setter accessor/mutator methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method).

So this:

```
public class Person {

    private String name ;

    public String getName( ) {
        return this.name ;
    }

    public void setName( String nameArg ) {
        this.name = nameArg ;
    }

}
```

…would become this:

```
import java.beans.BeanProperty;

public class Person {

    @BeanProperty
    public String name ;

}
```

Yet when I try this in a Java 9 project in IntelliJ 2017.2.2, I get error in the IDE on the "@" annotation saying:

> '@BeanProperty' not applicable to field

Compiler reports error:

> Error:(8, 5) java: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration

➠ Have I misunderstood the purpose of these new annotations? Or do I have some syntax problem?

I have not found any documentation other than the JEP and JavaDoc linked above.

I am experimenting with the recent release candidates for Java 9, currently Java 9+181 on macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

Comment: By the way, the new [*Records*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359) feature being previewed in Java 14 may address your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/beans/BeanProperty.html) says `BeanProperty` is `@Target(METHOD)`. Looks like it’s a way to customize [`PropertyDescriptor`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html)s without having to create a [`BeanInfo`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) implementation.  I don’t think it was intended to work like [*Lombok*](https://projectlombok.org).  (And thank goodness—see [Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters) for all the reasons explicit methods are a good idea.)