Class not found: Java.lang.ObjectBeanInfo
I am upgrading a project from Java 8 to Java 11 (yes, I know there's more recent).  One web app uses JideSoft, and we upgraded this from 3.5 to 3.7.15.  For legacy reasons, the web app does not use any dependency resolution, though most of the project's cross-app modules use Ivy.
When the app runs, the app's log reports a whole bunch of ClassNotFoundException errors to the console and not through Log4J's logging.  I believe these two classes are the key to my issues:
java.lang.ObjectBeanInfo
java.lang.ObjectCustomizer

There were several other jide.*.Product classes not found.  I resolved this by adding the appropriate new jar files to my build.xml and supporting files.  There are also several other classes not found, such as com.jidesoft.plaf.basic.BasicCustomizer, com.jidesoft.plaf.basic.BasicInitializer, org.apache.log4j.LayoutBeanInfo, and org.apache.log4j.LayoutCustomizer.  I believe most or all of these will be resolved if I can just address ObjectBeanInfo - though I am open to correction on this.
None of the other Java web apps in this project have had this issue.
Given that the only relevant changes have been the upgrades to Java and JideSoft, what do I need to do to resolve this issue?

Java doesn't have the classes java.lang.ObjectBeanInfo and java.lang.ObjectCustomizer (they were never part of the java.lang package nor any JDK/JRE package). It seems that these class names are auto-generated by some tool (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529737/javabean-and-relation-with-beaninfo-are-they-related) but since most Java bean classes do not have these classes either it should not be a problem if these do not exist.

@ThomasKläger So if these classes are auto-generated, why would my app not be generating them?

Not the classes are auto-generated - the class names are. The Java Beans Specification says that a Java Bean class XY may have two additional classes named XYBeanInfo (implementing java.beans.BeanInfo) and XYCustomizer (implementing java.beans.Customizer) and tools may look for these two classes but must work even if these classes do not exist. Writing those classes is the responsability of the author of the XY class (if they whish to do so), but since java.lang.Object is not a bean there is no reason for these two classes to exist.

@ThomasKläger Interesting.  Perhaps I should look at the runtime environment instead of hunting in the build environment.

Does the application otherwise work? Maybe it’s just an issue of whoever is logging ephemeral recoverable exceptions.

@Holger: No, the application does not actually run.  It's supposed to have a UI, but the UI never appears.

Can you post a complete stack trace?

@Holger: When I generated a complete stack trace I discovered the actual exception that gave me a problem was totally unrelated to Beans.  Thanks for getting me to look at the correct exception!
